# Serializable issue with List with Session stored in SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, serialization, session-state, serializable

We are using .Net 4.0 and SQL Server for our Session Store.

We have marked all our objects as [Serializable] but we are still getting the error:

```
System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to serialize the session state.
```

In turns out the issue is with a call to a ToList method we have implemented

```
if (licenseHoldings != null && licenseHoldings.**ToList()**.Any())
```

And the implementation of LicenseHoldings.cs :

```
[Serializable]
public class LicenseHoldings
{

    public MyEnum myEnum{ get; set; }

    public MySerializableObject mySerializableObject { get; set; }


    public List<MySerializableObjectBaseClass> ToList()
    {
        var list = new List<MySerializableObjectBaseClass>();

        if (mySerializableObject != null)
            list.Add(mySerializableObject  );
```

...

```
        return list;
    }
}
```

Why is a List of a serializable objects not serializable to a SQL Server session?

Comment: I think we're going to need to see more of your LicenseHoldings class.  Such as at least the class declaration, all of the fields, and any auto-properties, so that we can understand what data is contained inside of LicenseHoldings.

Comment: Can you try a quick experiment and simply rename the ToList method to something else, like "MyToList" for example?

Comment: It was worth a try Rajeev but it didnt fix the issue. Any ideas whether a List should be serializable to a session?

Comment: As far as I know, a List should absolutely be serializable to a Session, as long as the objects inside the List are themselves serializable.  But here's the thing ... you don't have a List.  Looking at the LicenseHoldings class, I don't see any Lists anywhere.  The data inside this class consists of only MyEnum and MySerializableObject.  Where's the List?  Sure, you have a ToList() method that returns a List, but that's irrelevant.  Methods and their return values do not get serialized.

Comment: Thanks for your help Rajeev but we've identified the issue - see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

The issue in this case was that the object MySerializableObjectBaseClass had a reference to an IEnumerable, ie. an interface which is not serializable.

We replaced IEnumerable with a List and all was well in the world..